# How do I know if I've already unlocked a pilot?

Tags: into-the-breach

After receiving a new pilot during a run, that pilot is permanently unlocked for use at the start of a new game. This makes it worthwhile to grab any new pilot even if not planning to use them in the current run, as even when assigned to islands (read "sold"), the pilots are still unlocked.

However, I can't remember all of the pilots I've unlocked. Sometimes I found myself having to choose between a weapon and a pilot from a Perfect Island reward, and I gave up on a cool weapon for a pilot I didn't think I had unlocked, but which I had. While I can sell the pilot and spend the reputation on something else, I might've preferred picking up a weapon instead of a pilot I don't need.

In order to prevent this, is there a way to check if I've unlocked a specific pilot before picking him as my Perfect Island reward?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you can check which pilots you have unlocked whenever your want - I just checked to be sure and it seems you **can check while the Perfect Island reward selection screen is up** as well as any other time by:

1. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click the cog in the top-left to open the menu.
2. Click "Main Menu"
3. Click "Statistics", in the bottom left
4. Click "Change Pilot", vaguely in the middle

This leads to a screen where you can choose one of your unlocked pilots to view your stats with, of course only the pilots you have unlocked are available to choose from and so you can tell if your reward choice pilot is already unlocked or not.

Comment: Ahh, it's good to see Subset Games took preserving game state seriously. I can vaguely recall a couple games where pressing 'Esc' in this situation would either not work or be treated as *"no, thanks"*...